# Odd/even styling divs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a page with multiple divs, i want to change the background-color property based on the odd and even rule, the first two divs are not included in the count so i want it to start from section four which should be odd because it's the first one but it's not working it always stays even, here is my code:

```css
.box:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
<div class="box">Hello World</div>
<div class="box">Hello World</div>
<div class="box">Hello World</div>
<div class="box">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: No, it's not. `nth-child` is indexed from 1.

Comment: @CRice nope, it starts at 1, that's why the 4th hello world is red

Comment: @Sphinx That's incorrect. `nth-child` counts all child elements, period. Adding a class to the selector, like `.box` acts as a filter, only applying to elements that are children and have the class box. @nickyjack The first element has an index of one. And what does JavaScript have to do with this?

Comment: Just reverse your odd and even, problem solved

Comment: @j08691, I just tested it, you are correct. Thanks.

Comment: The div you're trying to target might be the first .box, but it's the fourth child. That's why it's counted as an odd: nth-child doesn't care about classes.

Answer (score 0):

The fourth is even. If you want it counted differently, make it the first (or odd) child in a different container.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box:odd").css('background-color','yellow');
  $(".box:even").css('background-color','red');
});
```

Source (example with paragraphs): https://codepen.io/cibily/pen/hCDjF

Comment: @nickyjack this will work as jQuery are only selecting and extracting the .box elements, it's a forced way to apply it to some elements letting others out.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because they are siblings or childs of the same parent, so it does not matter that you're trying to select only those with class, it counts sibling tags.
So it's not the first (odd), it's the fourth (even).

Simply change it to:

```
.box:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

And you'll get the colors in your desired order.

Comment: `"brothers"` --> the correct word is siblings

Comment: Let's change that to siblings before someone say it should be called sisters and brothers

Comment: lol yup hahaha it was to maintain children like reference